# A query that uses variables works in PHPMyAdmin, but not in a PHP script

Tags: php, sql, variables, mysqli, phpmyadmin

The following query returns the expected result when I use the SQL input box in PHPMyAdmin, however in a PHP MySQLi query (`$sql->query()`) an error occurs.

```
SET @a = 5;
SET @b = (SELECT `b` FROM `t` WHERE `c`=@a);
SELECT @b;
```

The error I get is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @b= (SELECT `b` FROM `t' at line 2

Comment: http://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing 3 queries instead of 1 so you would need [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead of `query()`.

Comment: Does multi_query work for single queries? i.e could I use multi_query for just `SELECT `b` FROM `t` WHERE `c`='5'`

Comment: @user3887706 `Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon. `

Comment: Yes it does work. The liked manual page says `Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.`